# Calculating average case complexity of Quicksort

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o, quicksort, recurrence

I'm trying to calculate the `big-O` for Worst/Best/Average case of QuickSort using recurrence relations. My understanding is that the efficiency of your implementation is depends on how good the partition function is.

**Worst Case**: pivot always leaves one side empty

- T(N) = N + T(N-1) + T(1)
- T(N) = N + T(N-1)
- T(N) ~ N<sup>2</sup>/2 => `O(n^2)`

**Best Case**: pivot divides elements equally

- T(N) = N + T(N/2) + T(N/2)
- T(N) = N + 2T(N/2) [Master Theorem]
- T(N) ~ Nlog(N) => `O(nlogn)`

**Average Case**: This is where I'm confused how to represent the recurrence relation or how to approach it in general.

I know the *average case* big-O for Quicksort is `O(nlogn)` I'm just unsure how to derive it.

Comment: I guess, the best case is not O(nlogn). the best case is the sorted array as an input and it that case, the complexity seems to be lower

Comment: apparently the average case is O(nlogn)

Comment: So I was thinking of the best case partition function which would split the elements into two equal halves. I agree that the best case input is a sorted array.

Comment: regarding my first comment, my mistake, the comparison sort cannot have complexity less than O(nlogn). I guess the difference between average and best cases is the computation constant which is not included into the final big-Oh notation, hence at the end they appear to be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pick the pivot, the worst you can do is 0 | n and the best you can do is n/2 | n/2. The average case will find you getting a split of something more like n/4 | 3n/4, assuming uniform randomness. Plug that in and you get O(nlogn) once constants are eliminated.